# Converting spreadsheet to a text file with new lines

Tags: text, newline, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet (.ods format) that looks like this:

```
Column A        Column B
abstemious      marked by restraint
ameliorate      to make better or more tolerable
amphora         an ancient jar with 2 handles on the top
```

How can I convert it to a text file with the following format?

```
Q: abstemious
A: marked by restraint

Q: ameliorate      
A: to make better or more tolerable

Q: amphora         
A: an ancient jar with 2 handles on the top
```

Note the Q:, A:, and the new lines. I searched on Google and stack overflow and tried many things including converting to .csv as an intermediate step and using "find and replace", creating columns with "\n" in the spreadsheet, and also using "#13#10" which should indicate a new line but it doesn't seem to translate to the final .txt file.

Also, for formatting this post, I indented everything by 4 spaces and typed by hand, is there a better way to simulate a spreadsheet on stack overflow (eg if I was going to post something more complicated)? I looked at http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax but it is not clear what I would do if I wanted to post part of a spreadsheet with multiple columns and rows. I searched on this topic and also didn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Your formatting question might get a better answer on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much easier way to do it but I figured out one way. First, use a symbol that does not appear in the file (eg, '$') as a field separator and convert the .ods to a .csv. Next I wrote this code in Python:

```
def convert():
    f = open(r'name_of_file.csv','r')
    contents = f.read()
    contents = contents.split('\n')
    contents.pop()

    p = []

    for element in contents:
        p.append(element.split('$'))

    for element in p:
        print('Q: ' + element[0])
        print('A: ' + element[1])
        print('')
```

No reason to post other answers as this should suffice now that the program is written.